# Manually assigning points to line

Tags: qgis-3, point, line

I am fairly new to QGIS.

I have about 100 georeferenced counting stations for Munich and a street network given. However, both are from different sources and the counting stations need to be assigned to specific street links. Since the georeferencing of the points was not done accurately enough and often the data is even missing, I cannot use an algorithm for this. So my plan is to manually assign the points to the street links.

My desired outcome would be a street network where some lines have a Detector_ID drawn from the points in its attribute table. For street links without detectors, I would just leave this field empty.

Is there an easy/convenient way to assign the points to the street links *manually* and connect the attributes?

[image: example for the georeferencing]

[image: an additional PDF holds the detailed description of where the counting stations are located (street, direction, )]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manually assign values from a feature to another, you could use QGIS Actions on both layers.

On the point layer, create an action to copy the `id` field (or whatever information you want to transfer).

Right click on the layer, go to `properties` then `actions` then add a new action of type `python` on `field` and `feature`

```py
from qgis.core import QgsSettings
s = QgsSettings();
s.setValue("station_point_id",[% "id" %]);
```

[image]

Then add an action (same type/target) on the road layer to retrieve the saved point ID (or else) and to assign it to the current feature.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsSettings
s = QgsSettings();
pt_id = s.value("station_point_id");
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
layer_obj = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
fid = [%$id%]
fld = layer_obj.fields().lookupField('pt_id')
layer_obj.changeAttributeValue(fid, fld, pt_id)
```

[image]

You can now right click on a point and select "copy point" then right click on a road and select "set point ID"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I will try it out today - this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You just need a field common to both the streets and points. Assuming your streets layer has a field with unique identifier, you can create a new field in your points layer (with a similar name) and enter the street identifier for each. Then you can easily use a join or a relation to link the data.

Streets layer with unique identifier:

[image]

Manually create a similar field in your points layer:

[image]

[image]

To add the attributes of the `counting stations` to the `streets` you can then make a join on the streets layer (`Right-click layer name > Layer Properties > Joins`)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This helps a lot!