# QGIS - replace 'Reuse last entered attribute values' with attrributes from any existing object

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

How do I get attribute values from the selected existing object for creating a new one (replace ' Reuse last entered values')?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/425880/128665) help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.